# Handling multiple ext-js combolists in selenium, java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, extjs

I'm trying to populate some fields on ext-js generated page using Java with Selenium. Code:

```
public void ClickListBoxItem(String name) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    if(name==null || name=="") return;
    List<WebElement> items = WD.findElements(By.cssSelector(".x-layer.x-combo-list .x-combo-list-inner .x-combo-list-item"));
    Thread.sleep(200);
    for(WebElement item:items)
        if(name.contains(item.getText())) {
            je.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",item);
            return;
    }
}
public void Next(String id)
    {
        WebElement we = WD.findElement(By.cssSelector("#"+id)).findElement(By.xpath("following-sibling::*[1]"));
        je.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",we);
    }
```

And the procedure for each dropdown menu is:

```
public void FillSth() throws InterruptedException {
        Next("sth");
        ClickListBoxItem(someString);
    }
```

Unfortunately, it works only for the first try. When i call the function FillSth() more than one time, previously filled combos' values become empty. Moreover, items list seem to grow larger after each call. When called once, selected option from x-combolist stays there for good. What should i do to make those values stay there?

EDIT: Found out that combolist doesn't lose x-form-focus class when clicking on item and moving to another, perhaps this is the cause.

Comment: Problem solved. Added [style*='visibility: visible';] to my css selector and everything works fine. It's also better to use findelements() method to get the list, and then check visibility for each element to ensure that this is the one we're looking for (sometimes there were several elements with same name on my page and i tried to click non-visible one).